# Multiple field values to subreport error

Tags: join, reporting-services, parameters

I have a parent report that feeds one of the field values into a subreport. But the problem is that there this field value can include multiple records.  For simplicity, assume that this field value is called color, where possible values might be orange, red, and green.  I need to pass all of these value to the subreport, not just one.  I have tried passing the values this way into the Color parameter of the subreport:

```
=Fields!Color.Value
```

But this doesn't work and gives me an error.  I have also tried:

```
=join(Fields!Color.Value,",")
```

This also gives me an error on the subreport

I have also tried both of the above as an expression in a textbox in the parent report and I get #Error displayed on the parent report.  I was able to successfully get just the first value to appear by using a similar expression and the First function.  But I am not able to get all of the values to display in this textbox on the parent report?  how can I do this or at least pass all of the values to this subreport?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending multiple values in ssrs parameter to subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387950/sending-multiple-values-in-ssrs-parameter-to-subreport)

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is if Color is already a parameter - I would pass this expression in the subreport:

=Parameters!Color.Value

If Color is not a parameter, I would add a column to the driving dataset in the parent report using a SELECT ... FOR XML to concatenate the relevant Color values together.  Then you can pass that field to the subreport.